# My constructor specifies at least one value for construction, and yet it can be default constructed

Tags: c++, class, constructor, default-value, default-constructor

Take the following class:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(std::string bar_, int baz_ = 7)
    :bar(bar_)
    ,baz(baz_)
    {}

private:
    std::string bar;
    int baz;
};
```

Since **Foo(std::string bar_, int baz_ = 7);** is my only constructor, the compiler shouldn't implement a default constructor for me right?  I would think that the only two ways I could construct this class are:

```
Foo foo("foo");  
//or  
Foo foo("foo",0);  
//plus copy constructor and overloaded assignment operator.
```

Yet, why is this possible?

```
int main(){

    Foo foo();
}
```

I don't understand how I can default construct a class when the only public constructor requires a value for its first parameter.  Making the default constructor private or trying to C++11 delete it, makes no difference.  How is this happening?
http://ideone.com/CL7IZo

Comment: symbol `foo` in main is a function, not an instance of type Foo.

Comment: Try instantiating your object without the parenthesises (how do I even write that in english), then read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse :)

Comment: Why has this exact syntax issue come up three times in the last 10 hours?

Comment: @Nbr44, s/parenthesises/parentheses and you're good.

Comment: @mythagel a function call to what?  I have no function called foo(void);

Comment: Don't worry. Most of us have gone through this pesky initiation.

Comment: Foo foo(); actually indicates to the compiler that you are `declaring` a function named `foo()` of type `Foo` and taking no parameters. dont use parenthesises.

Comment: @Koushik ohhhhhh... son of a syntax!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `Foo foo();` is a forward declaration of a function which returns a `Foo` and takes no arguments.  Use `Foo foo;` instead and you will get your error.